# Change default variable value display in tbl_regression/tbl_uvregression and tbl_summary? #gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

After running a model e.g. cox model, I would like to change the default variable values on the table rows e.g. instead of the default Grade variable values: "I", "II", "III", I would like to have "A", "B", "C" respectively displayed instead.

1. How can I do that for **tbl_regression** and **tbl_uvregression**
   results?
2. How would one also do that with the **tbl_summary**
   results?

Here is an example code:

```
coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt + grade + age, trial) %>%
tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to make this change is the same for all gtsummary tables: update your data before you pipe it into the summarizing table.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.3.6'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(grade) %>%
  # update grade levels
  mutate(grade = factor(grade, labels = c("A", "B", "C"))) %>%
  tbl_summary()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how one pipes your solution with regression tables e.g. the coxph model, Could you kindly show me an example? Also, in your example you directly changed the grade value labels from "I", "II", "III" to "A", "B", "C" without explicit reference to the former. Can one explicitly map "A" to "I" so as to be sure of the relabelling in cases where the ordering of the values is not clearly defined?

Comment: Save a new table with the modifications, then use the new table in your model.

`trial2 <-
  trial %>%
  select(grade) %>%
  mutate(grade = factor(grade, labels = c("A", "B", "C")))` Then use `coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt + grade + age, trial2)`