# modify labels of categorical variables gtsummary

Tags: label, gtsummary

I am using the gtsummary package to generate tables. I have seen that in order to change the variable labels we should include something like:

I consider the mtcars data set.

```
 mtcars |> select(mpg,cyl) |> tbl_summary(label=list(mpg~"meter per gallon",cyl="Cylinder"))
```

[image]

But I would like to change the labels of the values 4,6,8 coming from Cylinder variable.

I mean, instead of 4,6, and 8 in the table I would like to see Four, Six and eight for example.

I was trying something like this but it does not works.

```
mtcars |> select(mpg,cyl) |> tbl_summary(label=list(mpg~"meter per gallon",cyl~"Cylinder","4"~"Four","6"~"Six","8"~"Eight"))
```

Comment: You'll want to modify the levels before you pipe the data frame into tbl_summary(). I recommend using the forcats package: there are so many great functions for modifying levels of a variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default variable value display in tbl\_regression/tbl\_uvregression and tbl\_summary? #gtsummary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716058/change-default-variable-value-display-in-tbl-regression-tbl-uvregression-and-tbl)